# Temperature not changing in my code for 1-D heat equation: Explicit Scheme

Tags: heat-transfer, matlab, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve the following 1-D heat equation with provided boundary conditions using explicit scheme on Matlab. I have been trying to plot the results but I realized that my temperatures are not changing. How can I solve problem and include the boundary condition?

```
clc; clear all; close all; 

a=0.45*10^-5;
U_Initial= 30+273.15; %converting to kelvin
U_Wall = 20+273.15; %converting to kelvin
U_BC = 100+273.15; %converting to kelvin
dt= 0.01;
dr= 1;
Lambda= (a*dt)/(dr)^2;
t=1:dt:3600;
r= 3:dr:100;
U = zeros(length(r),length(t));
U(:,1)= U_Initial;
U(1,:)=U_BC;
U(end,:)=U_Wall;
for j= 1:1:length(t)-1
   for i=2:1:length(r)-1
     U(i,j+1)= U(i,j)+Lambda*((dr/r(i))*(U(i+1,j)-U(i-1,j))+ (U(i+1,j)-2*U(i,j)+U(i-1,j)));
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This stackexchange doesn't really seek to solve these homework-like problems directly. However, I can offer some hints on how to proceed.

Are you sure the scale of `a` and `lambda` are correct? When I assign `a=0.1`, a reasonable profile develops. Consider non-dimensionalizing your problem so the variables all scale from 0 to 1. These kinds of errors tend to disappear when you formalize the math in this way. Once you have a non-dimensional solution, you can rescale easily.

Be aware that MATLAB also has built in PDE solvers. You might start [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/partial-differential-equations.html) to read up on the general approach and getting your problem in the right form, and then use [`pdepe`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html).

On a side note, look up [`linspace()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) as opposed to using the colon operator `:` for ranges with non-integer steps. The colon operator will leave out the last step in cases like `1:0.6:2`, which produces `[ 1 1.6 ]`. Note that `2` is missing, which is probably not what you intended.